# jq - find latest container image tag for a specific minor branch

Tags: json, jq, text-processing

crrently I am writing a small script to find out if newer images, which are defined in my docker-compose, are available on a registry.

To get a list of all available tags I use skopeo and get the following output.

```json
{
  "Repository": "registry.example:8080/my-namespace/my-app",
  "Tags": [
    "84.3200.0-alpha-1",
    "84.3200.0-alpha-2",
    "84.3200.0-alpha-3",
    "84.3200.1",
    "84.3300.0-alpha-1",
    "84.3300.0-alpha-2",
    "84.3300.1",
    "84.3400.0-alpha-1",
    "84.3400.0-alpha-2",
    "84.3400.0-alpha-3",
    "84.3400.0-alpha-4",
    "84.3400.1",
    "84.3400.2",
    "84.3500.0-alpha-1",
    "84.3500.0-alpha-2",
    "84.3500.1",
    "84.3500.2",
    "84.3502.1",
    "84.3600.1",
    "84.3600.2",
    "84.3600.3",
    "84.3600.4",
    "latest"
  ]
}
```

Now, in my `docker-compose.yaml` is currently the following image tag defined: `image: registry.example:8080/my-namespace/my-app:84.3400.0-alpha-1`. With `jq` I want to sort and filter the json to get the latest version of 84.3400 branch. Which is tag `84.3400.2`.

There are also newer tags available, for example for the branch `84.3500.x` and `84.3600.x`. This images should not be used to detect the latest version until any one has updated the tag inside the `docker-compose.yaml` manually to one of the this branch.

Has any one a good idea how to sort and filter the json to get the latest version of the branch?

## EDIT:

Hello, the solution from @inian is incomplete because the sort command sorts the characters one by one. This means that version `84.3400.2` is greater than `84.3400.12`.

Does anyone have an idea how I can sort the versions correctly in ascending order?

Here is an adapted json:

```json
{
  "Repository": "registry.example:8080/my-namespace/my-app",
  "Tags": [
    "84.3400.1",
    "84.3400.12",
    "84.3400.2",
    "latest"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Are you aware that it is not valid JSON?

Comment: No, but thanks. I marked the repository server and this leads to the incorrect json

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the base version as a variable and sort on that. E.g. for your provided input

```
jq --arg base "84.3400" '.Tags | map(select(startswith($base))) | sort | last'
```

This works, if your versions are named *as* int the question. In-place of `last`, you could also just do `reverse | first`

Comment: Could you please clarify why you've chosen `map`? I'd came up with `[ .Tags[] | select(startswith("84.3400.")) ] | last` and were curious why you'd choose `map`.

Comment: Well you add `[..]` over the whole filter before `|last`, I don't like doing that. Doing `map()` allows me to work on arrays directly

Comment: Ah yea, understand the logic, so it's more of a person preference? Or is the map 'a lot' faster? Just wondering if my way is 'wrong' somehow

Comment: @0stone0 `map(f)` is defined as `[.[]|f]`. So they are the same

Answer (score 0):

Demo https://jqplay.org/s/t8dyM4tmmJ

```
filter:
"84.3400" as $base | .Tags | map(select(startswith($base))) | sort | last
```